# Monitor history of delegated user

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Which is the behavior of history list api in case of delegated user? E.g. Can I have an information like "user X has deleted Y message" ? Thanks

Comment: If you have check the documentation, the methods that are supported are [create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/create), [delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/delete), [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/get) and [list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/delegates/list). Checking the coverage of the delegate [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350), it was not mentioned that a delegated user has such power.

Comment: probably I was not clear, the issue is not to delete a delegate user using API, but log if a delegate user delete a message (priviliged that the delegate user have)